# Onclick for a LinkButton

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ShowEventUnusualByDate" OnClick="ShowEventUnusualByDate_Click" CssClass="btn" runat="server"><i class="la la-check"></i>GO</asp:LinkButton>
```

And afterward the jQuery:

```
$('#Main_ShowEventUnusualByName').click(function () {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

But on click, nothing appears to happen.

Comment: What is the resulting client-side HTML for the `LinkButton`?  Where is it on the page in relation to the JavaScript code?

Comment: f12 shows it as 'a'.  Because it's LinkButton?

Comment: @ShneorBachar: edit your question and post the whole A element please.

Comment: @ShneorBachar: Well, if it's *only* an `<a>` (with no `id`) then the jQuery selector won't find it.  JavaScript doesn't see your server-side code, only the resulting client-side code.  So debugging to narrow down the problem needs to include examining the client-side code.  Perhaps you could edit the question to include a runnable code snippet demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I think it's because there the JQuery is executing, changing the color to red, then the code behind function `ShowEventUnusualByDate_Click` is executed, then there is a postback (due to link button), the page is reloading and resetting the color. Everything could be executing, it's just getting wiped out immediately. What does `ShowEventUnusualByDate_Click` do?

Comment: He must be turning to the server! what can do

Comment: @ShneorBachar set the color from the code behind and skip all jquery. Like: your link button - `ShowEventUnusualByDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`

Comment: ShowEventUnusualByDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; Only the text is red   I want to paint the background of button

Comment: ShowEventUnusualByDate.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;  That, too, doesn't do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you are taking wrong ID in jquery selector, because the button ID is some different.

I have checked it two ways:

1. Taking a simple button  of HTML and changing the text color on click - **Passed**.
2. Taking your ASP.Net server control button in my IDE (for test purpose) - **Passed**

**Please note:** If you run the snippet you might get error because SO code editor doesn't support asp.net server controls.  You must check it on your Visual Studio IDE only.

```js
$('#ShowEventUnusualByDate').click(function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="ShowEventUnusualByDate" OnClick="ShowEventUnusualByDate_Click" CssClass="btn" runat="server"><i class="la la-check"></i>GO</asp:LinkButton>
```

Hope this helps.